# why does it just change the first format of the first number in table

Tags: html, jquery, formatting

I want to format all numbers in a table cell. The selection is fine, console.log gives me:

```
    47,560,820
    4,648,787
    1,020,403
    4,122,147
    2,731,035
    3,817,139
```

Code:

```
    $(document.body).ready(function () {
      $(".dashboardArtistsTable tr").each(function (i) {
        var n = $(this).find(".dashboardFollowersNr").html();
        var formattedNumbers = numeral(n).format("0,0");
        console.log(formattedNumbers);
        $(".dashboardFollowersNr").html(formattedNumbers);
      });
    });
```

The problem is the last line. I just don't know how to change it. Now all numbers are replaced with the first one.

Each table row contains:

```
<tr>
<td id="cellFollowers">
<p class="dashboardFollowersNr" id="followers-nr">47560820</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and the desired output as well? It would be very helpful.

Comment: `$(this).find(".dashboardFollowersNr").html();` will need the same selector applied to `$(this).find(".dashboardFollowersNr").html(formattedNumbers);` - or put another way `$(".dashboardFollowersNr").html(formattedNumbers)` applies to all, so you'll need a `$(this)...` in there as you do when retrieving the numbers

Comment: As above, without the HTML, we can't know if `$(this).find(".dashboardFollowersNr")` gives one element or many - you may also need to loop through these values before getting `.html()` (otherwise it's a combined value)

Comment: desired output is as given in console.log, so the numbers shall be formated with commas

Comment: offtopic as not pertaining to the solution: id= should be unique, not the same across multiple rows: `id="followers-nr`

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes, I know, will change that. There are more issues in this project. It's my first one, all about learning. The current goal is to get it live. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are currently having is when you do:

```
$(".dashboardFollowersNr").html(formattedNumbers);
```

You are setting the html for all of that class, not the specific one in that row

You really don't need to loop over each row and could just loop over each of the `dashboardFollowersNr` class.

You could use `text(function)` or `html(function)` to do the looping internally for you

Try

```
$(".dashboardFollowersNr").text(function(index, currText){
    return numeral(currText).format("0,0");
})
```

Comment: Is this `numeral(currText).format("0,0");` using a plug-in? It's been a while since I used jQuery, but I've not come across the `numeral()`, or `format()`, function before.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I assume it is some number library. I don't recognize it either